# Flask request.form["name"] returns just one token

Tags: python, html, flask

Hello i dont know maybe it is a rookie question problem is this i have a button inside the html

```
<button class="btn" id="name" name="name" type="submit" value={{form.title}}>Button</button>
```

and i am trying to take the value from flask as seen below

```
if 'name' in request.form:
    title = request.form["name"]
```

Problem is this request.form["name"] returns just one token .for example if the value is "John Doe" it just returns "John" and i need the full value 
i tried

```
json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
            title = json_data["name"]
```

but that didnt work either

Edit :As i debug the code more i see that request.form["name"] takes correct value but

```
 `value={{form.title}}`
```

gives the value first token of the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose value with `"{{form.title}}"`. You should get whole value as a string.

Comment: thank you dude that work but before when i closed the tag the value was just {{form.title}} maybe ı just miss a paranthesis